# How to divide unordered set into subsets in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, set

I need a predicate that splits a given set into subsets

What I have so far:

```
divide_set(S, Sd) :-
  length(S, L),
  between(1, L, N),
  length(Sd, N),
  append(Sd, S),
  forall(member(M, Sd), M \= []).
```

Which gives me these results:

```
?- divide_set([a, b, c, d, e, f], Sd).
Sd = [[a, b, c, d, e, f]] ;
Sd = [[a], [b, c, d, e, f]] ;
Sd = [[a, b], [c, d, e, f]] ;
Sd = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]] ;
Sd = [[a, b, c, d], [e, f]] ;
Sd = [[a, b, c, d, e], [f]] ;
...
```

So the set is treated as an ordered set however I want `[a, f]` for instance to be included too.

**How can I extend my predicate so that I get subsets rather than subsquences?**

*(I could do it for every possible sequence, but I think that'd not be the best solution)*

Comment: Any solution that relies too much on `append/3` is going to have the same problem

Comment: @DanielLyons Any suggestions?

Comment: My favorite workhorse for these kinds of problems is [`select/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/3) but I'm not entirely sure how to apply it to this problem, because you want to get some arbitrary number of sets. You'll be bounded by the number of elements though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, kind of a tricky problem! My first thought was to try something like this, a declarative reading:

```
superset(Superset, Subsets) :-
  foreach(member(Subset, Subsets),
    foreach(member(X, Subset), member(X, Superset))).
```

This looks good on paper, but using `member/2` to generate leads to infinite recursion as it hallucinates massive lists that contain unbound variables. So that didn't work.

My next thought was, maybe I could just generate all permutations like you suggested. But as I imagined generating all the permutations and then building all possible lists around them, it started to sound like there would be a lot of repeated answers. So I came around to your opinion, that there is probably a more efficient way to do this.

Then I started out by making some example input/outputs, which looked like this:

```
divide_set([X,Y], [[X],[Y]]).
divide_set([X,Y], [[X,Y]]).

divide_set([X,Y,Z], [[X],[Y],[Z]]).
divide_set([X,Y,Z], [[X],[Y,Z]]).

divide_set([X,Y,Z], [[X,Y],[Z]]).
divide_set([X,Y,Z], [[X,Z],[Y]]).
divide_set([X,Y,Z], [[X,Y,Z]]).
```

Grouping them in this way helped me see an approach: one in which I either pull out the front item and recur, or pull out the front item and prepend it to the recursive result, which led me to this implementation:

```
divide_set([X], [[X]]).
divide_set([X|Remainder], [[X]|Rest]) :-
    divide_set(Remainder, Rest).
divide_set([X|Remainder], [[X|Subset]|RestButOne]) :-
    divide_set(Remainder, Rest),
    select(Subset, Rest, RestButOne).
```

I don't know for sure if this is right, but this is the output I get on your sample input:

```
?- divide_set([1,2,3,4], X).
X = [[1], [2], [3], [4]] ;
X = [[1], [2], [3, 4]] ;
X = [[1], [2, 3], [4]] ;
X = [[1], [2, 4], [3]] ;
X = [[1], [2, 3, 4]] ;
X = [[1, 2], [3], [4]] ;
X = [[1, 3], [2], [4]] ;
X = [[1, 4], [2], [3]] ;
X = [[1, 2], [3, 4]] ;
X = [[1, 3, 4], [2]] ;
X = [[1, 2, 3], [4]] ;
X = [[1, 4], [2, 3]] ;
X = [[1, 2, 4], [3]] ;
X = [[1, 3], [2, 4]] ;
X = [[1, 2, 3, 4]] ;
false.
```

I haven't done the math to see what we should get in terms of answers combinatorically, but at first blush this looks right to me. I see all the different sizes of subset I'd expect with four elements, and I see all the different quantities of subsets I'd expect. The work does diminish as it gets further into the recursion; you'll notice the number 1 never appears in the second or subsequent lists, 2 never appears in the 3rd or 4th subsets, etc. So I think there are reasonable odds of this being correct.

Also, the scenario you are interested in does occur:

```
?- divide_set([a, b, c, d, e, f], [[a,f]|Rest]).
Rest = [[b], [c], [d], [e]] ;
Rest = [[b], [c], [d, e]] ;
Rest = [[b], [c, d], [e]] ;
Rest = [[b], [c, e], [d]] ;
Rest = [[b], [c, d, e]] ;
Rest = [[b, c], [d], [e]] ;
Rest = [[b, d], [c], [e]] ;
Rest = [[b, e], [c], [d]] ;
Rest = [[b, c], [d, e]] ;
Rest = [[b, d, e], [c]] ;
Rest = [[b, c, d], [e]] ;
Rest = [[b, e], [c, d]] ;
Rest = [[b, c, e], [d]] ;
Rest = [[b, d], [c, e]] ;
Rest = [[b, c, d, e]] ;
false.
```